# spring boot (Resource server) and keycloak (Authorization server) and angular client app question for access token when i authenticate

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, keycloak-rest-api, pkce

*i used spring security 6 =>
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
return httpSecurity.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/api/home/**"))
.authorizeHttpRequests(httpRequests ->{httpRequests.requestMatchers("api/home/welcome").hasRole("USER");httpRequests.anyRequest().authenticated();})
.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
.build();
}
*app.properties =>
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8180/realms/oauth2-demo
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8180/realms/oauth2-demo/protocol/openid-connect/certs

*angular=>i installed library called angular-oauth2-oidc the probleme is when i authenticate for a user the access token retieve successfuly but whrn i add role to this user and retry again the access token failed to retieve it

*angular=>i installed library called angular-oauth2-oidc the probleme is when i authenticate for a user the access token retieve successfuly but whrn i add role to this user and retry again the access token failed to retieve it